# persist users selection in react-select after reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, persistence, react-select

I am new to react and I want to save the selection chosen by a user if I reload the page..
I have many react-select boxes so is it possible to save all these selections?

Comment: You may want to look at localStorage. Are you concerned the users will refresh the page? The big advantage of React is working within the virtual DOM so page reloads are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Normally the user is not going to reload the page it's completely true but the problem is that I have a file in the public folder that changes a lot so every time it changes the page reload by itself..

Comment: Recording the entry in localStorage on checkbox click might work for you then.